# Can one PlayStation Plus subscription be shared between multiple PSN accounts on the same machine?

Tags: psn, ps4, playstation-plus

I just purchased a new ps4 and found out that PlayStation Plus is required for online gameplay. My ps4 is shared with someone else at home so I want to ask if one PlayStation Plus subscription can be shared between multiple psn accounts on the same machine?

Comment: I very much doubt it.

Comment: No one's answering tho.....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the main thing you're concerned about is online multiplayer, then yes, all accounts on a single PS4 can play online if at least one if them has an active PS Plus subscription, and that PS4 console is set as the PS Plus account's "Primary PS4."

From [Sony's FAQ](http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5030/~/accessing-playstation%C2%AEplus-benefits-from-other-user-accounts-and-playstation):

> PlayStation®Plus benefits available to other non-subscribing users on your Primary PS4™:
>   - Online multiplayer (subject to any parental control settings on sub accounts)
>   - Play downloaded games purchased with PlayStation®Plus discount
>   - Play downloaded IGC games
>
> PlayStation®Plus benefits not available to other users on your Primary PS4™:
>   - Purchasing PlayStation®Plus discounted products from PlayStation Store
>   - Online game save storage
>   - Auto patch download
>   - PlayStation®Plus exclusive early access to game trials

Answer (score 6):

I recently bought a 2nd PS4 (unit 2).  I gave my old PS4 to my son (unit 1), which was my primary.  On unit 1 all user has all the benefits of ps plus, multiplayer included.  On unit 2, since I will be the only user on it, will have to sign in my name at all times to have my ps plus benefit.  Currently I can play destiny multiplayer, download free games on ps store, etc.   if another user signed in on unit 2, this would not work.  Only your primary ID would work on unit 2. Makes sense?

Comment: So does this mean you can play with your son on the same ps plus membership?

Answer (score 4):

PlayStation Plus online play limitations currently appear to be at the developer's discretion from my personal experience. Although this may change in the future. Your mileage may very over time.

Case in point: Using a PS4 with several user profiles created. Two of the accounts have PSN+ subscriptions. The others do not.

On the recent Destiny Alpha. The primary account had an Alpha key. Other accounts on the PS4 (both with and without PSN+) could boot the Alpha from their profile and play the initial game with on-line multi-player, but it appeared that some missions were locked out to PSN+ members only.

Warframe, downloaded and installed by the primary account was playable by non-PSN+ profiles with no issues.

On Resogun (when we tested it), all of the profiles could play on-line with friends, PSN+ subscription or not.

So, again, it will probably be a case by case basis but I'm going to guess that micro-transaction MMO's are going to be more liberal with access where as games with a user specific token (like an Assassin's Creed game) will only allow on-line play by the one account.

Comment: So signing into two separate psn accounts in two separate local accounts (e.g. User 1 and user 2) will require me two subscriptions to ps+ if I want to access multiplayer on both account, right??? Thanks for your answers anyway

Comment: No that is wrong, the above answers say that you only need one PS+ subscription for multiple users but it has to be the primary account that has the subscription.

Comment: @Colin is correct the account with the games downloaded needs to be the primary account on the system. But for the secondary non PSN+ accounts, access to on-line features is hit-or-miss currently.