# Game progress not showing logging in to 2nd ps4

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

My son has a PS4 at his mum's place and at mine. He purchased a game on my machine which he started at his mum's, but when logging back into mine, the game appears, but the progress hasn't transferred (and he needs to start the game again).

How can I fix this? His mum's PS4 is set as his primary one. I've tried all options I can think of, but would have thought it should be possible to start where he left off wherever he logs in.

Comment: What game is this? And do you know if he has PS+ on his account?

Comment: It's infamous second son. He did have ps+ but it expired. The game was purchased after it expired.  He also says the same thing happens if he takes a disc there, he logs in but there's no stored progress. Is he saving it in wrong place or does he need ps+? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cloud saving (having progress avialable on multiple consoles) Is only avialable to PS+ users, since you stated that he bought the game after he no longer had a PS+ subscription he / you would have to buy a PS+ subscription for cloud saving to be enabled. I don't know if you have access to that progress after the subscription runs out again though.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I have twins, would they both need ps+ subscriptions ? Thanks again

Comment: As i had to delete the previous comment because of a mistake on my side here is the proper explanation: If you want the twins progress to be shared across the consoles aswell, yes, both would need a ps+ subscription, there are certain features avialable to users of a PS4 if a Account who has PS+ has the console set as his primary. [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173614/148179) for a list of those features.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the fact that he does not have PlayStation Plus (PS+).  PS+ is required to save data to the cloud, so it can be used over several consoles.  Another problem might be that he isn't using the profile on the first PS4 that is connected to the PSN.

You can renew your PS+ membership on the first PS4, and back up your progress there, then make sure the profile he's playing games on is the profile connected to the PSN.