# Can you get banned for using a Playstation Plus trial from your primary account with other accounts?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

So I have two PSN accounts and I was wondering if this can happen with even single players?

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

Public information about ban reasons says nothing about game sharing or using multiple trials on one device. List of ban reasons (they are mostly related to online interactions):

- Modified System Software
- Modified Hardware
- Reversal of Charges
- Share/Hijack Account
- Offensive Images or Audio
- Exploiting a Game Glitch
- Verbal/Text Abuse
- Hate Speech
- Your Personal Information
- Another Person's Personal Information
- Abuse of Grief Reporting Function
- Impersonating Another User
- Spamming
- Grooming
- Sexual Harassment
- Account Scamming
- Impersonating an SIEA Representative
- Child Protection
- Inappropriate Online ID
- Team Killing
- Cheat Codes
- Voice Communication Blocking
- Uploading Pornographic or Obscene Image
- Community Standards Abuse
- Cheating
- False Registration Information
- Fraud
- Disrupting a Game

For details visit [Information on Banned Accounts and Consoles](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/Information-on-Banned-Accounts-and-Consoles).

And from my personal experience: I have 2 PSN accounts on my PS4, all purchases and PS+ subscriptions are done on one of them, user from another is able to play all the games (at least in single player). No bans for us so far. I will update this answer is I ever get banned :)

See also [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173614/144891) for details on account sharing.