# Can multiple sub-accounts play online at the same time?

Tags: ps4, psn

I just got the PS4. This subscription requirement is new to me. I like to play online games as do my 3 daughters and my son. Do you have you have to have multiple year subscriptions for online play so they can play together on games like Minecraft or Black Ops?

Comment: and https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/173452/144891

Comment: Can multple sub-accounts play online together on the ps4? Or does each child need a Playstation + account to play minecraft online games.

Comment: yes, but game itself should support local coop play. I know that games like Rocket League and Overcooked support it, not sure about Minecraft and Black Ops.