# Using a PSN account from India in Germany

Tags: ps4, psn

I have a PSN account from India in which I have a lot of trophies, but no games. I used to live in India, but recently moved to Germany.
I bought a new PS4 pro today in Germany and I was wondering whether I should keep using my Indian PSN account or create a new one? I don't want to lose any trophies I acquired earlier, but I don't want to get into a region locking mess also.

So, I just want to know if there'll be any potential issue I may face when I use my Indian PSN account on a German PS4 pro in Germany? I may want to buy a PS plus subscription on a later date and I certainly do not want to get into a legal trouble (if there's any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your Indian PSN account on a German PS4 without any *legal* problems.

What you can do:

- Create and/or use multiple PSN accounts from different regions on the same PS4.
- Play games from multiple regions on any PSN account, as long as your PS4 is registered as the *Primary PS4* for the account that owns the game, or you own the game disk and it is currently in your PS4.
- Earn trophies for any game, regardless from which region. Some games (usually Japanese ones) have different Trophy lists for different regions. You can earn Trophies from all lists (if you are willing to buy and play the same game multiple times for each region).
- [Share a PS+ subscription to play PS+ games, or play games online.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173614/46740)

What you ***can't*** do:

- Buy or download games or DLCs from a foreign region. To do this, you'll have to create a foreign PSN account, and buy or download the game using that other account.
- Share a PS+ subscription to redeem PS+ games, or access cloud storage or PS+ exclusive content.

Comment: So if I create another German PSN account and keep my Indian account as the primary account, should I buy DLC on the German PSN account, or will it be playable with Indian PSN account as well?
I am going to buy the games on Indian PSN account, if possible. Or I can use German PSN account for buying the games, and use Indian one for trophies. Can I do that?

Comment: @noob. You can do either: buy German games on your German account to play on your Indian account, or buy Indian games on your Indian account to play on your German account. You'll be able to earn Trophies on either account.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to check. I am assuming this is same for DLCs as well.

Comment: @noob. Correct, games or DLCs make no difference. Keep in mind that you ***must*** buy the DLC from the same region as the game. If you buy the game on your German account, and the DLC on your Indian account, the game *won't recognize* the DLC.

Comment: That's a good point. I think I'll by everything from my Indian account. It's cheaper there :-D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, games are not region locked for the PS4 and PSN accounts don't care which region you are in. I have successfully played Japanese games here in the US and have Japanese trophies with my regular US trophies (they are considered different games, so I have separate trophies for the Japanese and US versions of Catherine, for instance).

Your issue is that the PlayStation Store IS region specific. If you use an Indian PSN account, you will see the India PSN Store in Germany. I believe you only need to change your account's locale to change this, but cannot confirm this. Also I believe any DVD/Blu-ray playback is also region locked, but this may be the system's region and not the PSN account region, I'm not sure.

Comment: There's no way to change an account's locale.  You need to create an entirely new account.  There's not much downside, though, as you can purchase with the new account and play on the old one.