# Can I have 2 accounts from different regions and access the online store on PS5 all digital?

Tags: psn, region-lock, ps5

At the moment, I live ing India. When I get my PS5, I will link it with a PSN account that has its region set as India with an Indian credit card connected. In two years, I will move to France. Once I'm in France, as I cannot change the region of a PSN account after the fact, I create another PSN account with it's region set as France with a French credit card. I found that you can in fact have 2 psn accounts linked to the same console. However, my worry is that the games and the saved data of all the games that I played on my Indian PSN account with in India, will not be able to be played on my French PSN account.

So, after I move to France, will this mean that my only choice is to keep the Indian PSN account so as to not lose 2 years of saved game data and games bought, and use my French PSN account from then on in order to access the French Online store and buy games. This would mean I'd switch between my Indian and French PSN accounts on my ps to play whatever games I've bought in each respective account.

Ideally, I'd want to be able to have one PSN account and change its region later on, add my French credit card, delete my Indian credit card, change the address and continue playing the games I had bought when I was in India and buy new games now on the French online store. However, I saw that it is not possible to change the region of a PSN account after the account creation stage.

Knowing my situation and my goal, what is the best way for me to move forward. Just get a regular PS5 or is there something I can do about this situation on a PS5 All-Digital? If I'm unable to get a regular PS5 and the all-digital is my only option, what then?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! This question relates to PSN on the PS4, but it may nonetheless be useful. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357323/using-a-psn-account-from-india-in-germany?rq=1